# Why i have Error with my Java Spring Boot WebApp?

Tags: java, spring

I'm running a web app for physiotherapists in Java Spring Boot. While I have not put Log in Form, it asks me to put log in details when I run the program. I run the program from cmd and log into the web app via localhost.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZWcf.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMw2u.png)

Comment: Please do not use images of text, as users must retype the text therein. Images also pose a challenge to screen readers. Additionally, please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It may be helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do not use images. Please post the logs and all relevant data here

Answer (score 0):

You have added Spring Security to your application. Without any further configuration, it will create a Login Form for you. The default user is `user` and the password for this user will be automatically generated on startup. You can see it in your first screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZWcf.png